# Convert Object to Array in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Object :

```
"items":[{"id": 1, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"},
         {"id": 2, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"},
         {"id": 3, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"}]
```

And i would like to convert this object to an array.

I tried

```
const idItem = Object.keys(obj['items']).map(key => ({id: key, 
               value: obj['items']['id']}));
```

Result:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]
```

So it works but i don't know how to convert everything (name and content).

Comment: Just use `obj['items']`? The closing curly bracket `}` is a typo I guess.

Comment: Your provided definition items in your object is syntactically wrong, it has a "[" at the beginning, but a "}" at the end.... so what is "items" supposed to be, an array or an object?

Comment: Edited it was }]

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. It would be great if you could add your desired response in the question as well so it clears things out.

Comment: If you want a good answer, you need a good question. I mean, is not clear what you really want to do. Or what is the output you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like

```js
var obj={
"items":[{"id": 1, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"},
         {"id": 2, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"},
         {"id": 3, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"}
         ]
         }
         var data=obj['items'];
    console.log(data)
    var item=data.find(i=> i.id==3);
    console.log(item);
```

Comment: Yes i just want to do this and then i could diplay by id for example : console.log(obj['items'][3])

Comment: @Dia for that you can use find method check out updated ans

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator

```
const items  = [{"id": 1, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"},
         {"id": 2, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"},
         {"id": 3, "name": "A name", "content": "A content"}];

    console.log({...items}); // --> {0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {...}}
```